# Using System::IO::File::ReadAllLines() in C++/cli

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am trying to use the C# method  `System::IO::File::ReadAllLines()` in my C++ project, but every time I try and pass in a `System::String^` into the method it underlines the method and say:

> A value of type "cli::array<sytem::String^,1>" cannot be used to initialize an entity of    type "System::String^"

What does this mean? My code:

```
#define IO System::IO
int main()
{
  System::String ^ path = gcnew System::String("C:\\text.txt");
  System::String ^ lines = IO::File::ReadAllLines(path);
  return 0;
}
```

Also is there an alternative function in C++?

I have set up my project to use, /clr.

Let me know if you need any more information and I will provide it.

Comment: BTW, `ReadAllLines()` is not a “C# method”, it's a .Net method, but there is nothing C#-specific about it.

Comment: Use File::ReadAllText() if you in fact meant to get only a single string with all of the file content.  ReadAllLines() returns an array, just like the compiler error message says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood the error you are receiving. `ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings rather than a string containing the entire file contents. [`ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) returns a string containing the entire file contents.

```
// if you would like an array of strings
array<String^>^ lines = File::ReadAllLines(path);

// or

// if you would like a single string with the file contents
String^ lines = File::ReadAllText(path);
```